# MySQL Select both This and That

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The tables look like these:

```
Table: Shops

ShopCode   ShopName
--------   --------
A          Aladdin
B          Backstreet
C          Clerk's Store
D          Debs Tool

Table: Sale

ShopCode   Product
--------   -------
A          Hammer
A          Thermometer
A          Compass
B          Eraser
B          Hammer
C          Thermometer
C          Hammer
D          Thermometer
```

Find the name of the shops which sells BOTH Hammer and Thermometer. The result table would be

```
ShopName   
-------------- 
Aladdin
Clerk's Store
```

I thought the following query will work, but its returning empty set

```
mysql> SELECT Shops.ShopName FROM Shops
    -> JOIN Sale ON Shops.ShopCode=Sale.ShopCode
    -> WHERE Sale.Product='Hammer' AND Sale.Product='Thermometer'
    -> GROUP BY Shops.ShopCode;
```

Also tried with OR instead of AND, but not working (returning all the shops). What might be a possible solution?

Just to make it little bit clear, I want to select the shops that have both the items(hammer and thermo), even though shop B sells hammer and D sells Thermometer, they will not be included. Only A and C which is selling both the items should be on the result

Comment: You just forgot Sale.Product= 'Thermometer'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two fairly straight forward options.

You can join twice with the sale table, once per item. If you skip the `DISTINCT`, you may get duplicate values if the store sells more than one hammer or thermometer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.shopname
FROM shops s
JOIN sale s1 ON s.shopcode = s1.shopcode AND s1.product='hammer'
JOIN sale s2 ON s.shopcode = s2.shopcode AND s2.product='thermometer';
```

...or you can find all matches with hammer or thermometer and count how many distinct values there are. If there are two possible values and you get both, you're set.

```
SELECT s.shopname
FROM shops s
JOIN sale s1 ON s.shopcode = s1.shopcode
WHERE s1.product IN('hammer','thermometer')
GROUP BY s.shopname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s1.product)=2;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf57b/2).

Comment: The key issue is that you are working ROWS, and so when you want to see if a ROW of this exists and a ROW of that exists, all the joining and filtering is done on a row basis, thus you must rely on doing something like a count or aggregating and the rows and checking (like group_concat or count etc...);

Answer (score 2):

You can easily Join twice on the Sale table--once for hammers and once for Thermometers to get the store with BOTH Hammers and Theremoeteres

```
 SELECT s.ShopName FROM Shops s  
      JOIN Sale s1 ON s.ShopCode=s1.ShopCode AND s1.Product='Thermometer'
      JOIN Sale s2 ON s1.ShopCode=s2.ShopCode AND s2.Product='Hammer'
  GROUP BY s.ShopName
```

Comment: No you don't need to join multiple times. That can be a waste resources.

Comment: @Ray...is the Group By necessary.  Won't the Join take care of that?  Just curious...

Comment: @MikeTWebb As long as there is only one hammer or one theremometer per store, you can ditch the group by

Comment: You cannot guarantee how many products per store. Probably neither OP.

Comment: @Ray...cool, thanks....yeah, I was assuming one row per shopcode, product in table B.  I don't see quantity in either schema

Answer (score -3):

I Think the right Sql look like this:

```
mysql> SELECT Shops.ShopName FROM Shops
    -> JOIN Sale ON Shops.ShopCode=Sale.ShopCode
    -> WHERE Sale.Product='Hammer' AND Sale.Product 'Thermometer'
    -> GROUP BY Shops.ShopCode;
```

OR

```
mysql> SELECT Shops.ShopName FROM Shops
    -> JOIN Sale ON Shops.ShopCode=Sale.ShopCode
    -> WHERE Sale.Product IN ('Hammer', 'Thermometer')
    -> GROUP BY Shops.ShopCode;
```

Comment: IN is equivalent to multiple ORs not ANDs