# Getting number of rows with COUNT and WHERE IN with multiple values

Tags: mysql

im trying to query for amount of rows matching all conditions. My query is working like intended only for single value in condition. I wonder if im missing something or whole query should be reworked.

I have tables like (only question related columns):

```
 users:               categories:
╔═══════╦═══════════╗╔═══════╦═══════════╗
║  id   ║ user_type ║║  id   ║ name      ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╣╠═══════╬═══════════╣
║ id 1  ║ tutor     ║║ id 1  ║ name1     ║
║ id 2  ║ other     ║║ id 2  ║ name2     ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╝╚═══════╩═══════════╝
ads:
╔════════════╦══════════════╗
║ creator_id ║ category_id  ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╣
║ user.id1   ║ category.id1 ║
║ user.id2   ║ category.id2 ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╝
```

And query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS count FROM users
INNER JOIN ratings
ON users.id = receiver_id
LEFT JOIN ads
ON users.id = ads.creator_id
LEFT JOIN categories
ON categories.id = ads.category_id
WHERE user_type = "tutor"
AND categories.name IN ("economy","anatomy")
```

What i get:

> **count = 13** (which is number of matching rows for "economy" (10) + rows for "anatomy" (5) - rows matching both conditions (2), **10 + 5 - 2 = 13**)

For single value in condition, ex:

`AND categories.name IN ("economy")`

im getting proper outcome

What i need:

> **count = 2** (which is total number of rows that match all conditions)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to count users who tutor economy AND anatomy? Sample data and expected result (as text) would help.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i need. Only tutors that have ads with economy AND anatomy. Tutors that have ads with economy or anatomy alone shouldnt be counted. Something like: `if (user have ad economy && user have ad  anatomy) count++`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select both This and That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891870/mysql-select-both-this-and-that)